# Проблема с синхронизацией потоков.

Tags: многопоточность, java

```
   Добрый день,впервые работаю с потоками и возникла проблема в синхронизации.Потоков всего два - А генерирует значения а B его забирает и выводит себя столько раз,сколько получило от А,потоки общаются между собой через экземпляр класса Callme.
    Задача осложняется тем,что **кроме методов wait и notify использовать ничего 
нельзя**,даже флаги.

package 5variant_3_lab;

class A implements Runnable{//Поток созданный через реализацию Runnable
    Thread t;
    Callme target;
    int i;//переменная для вывода значения генератора

    public A(Callme targ){
        target = targ;
        t=new Thread(this,"Поток А");   
        t.start();
       }

   public void run(){ 
    synchronized(target){ 
         try{          
             i=target.generator();
             System.out.println("Поток A сгенерировал значение ["+i+"]");
             target.notify(); //Пробудить другой поток 
             target.wait();//Перейти в спящий режим самому    
            }
         catch(InterruptedException e){}
    }     
   }
}

class Callme{
  int count;
  int i;

     synchronized  int common(){ 
      count=i;      
      return count;       
     }
     synchronized  int generator(){
       i = (int)(9 * Math.random() + 1);
       return i;
     }
  }

class B extends Thread{//Поток созданный через расширение класса Thread
    Callme target;
    int count;// Переменная для хранения значения из метода common()
  B(Callme targ){       
      super("Поток B");
      target=targ;        
      start();
  }

  public void run(){
    synchronized(target){ 
      try{
         count=target.common();
         System.out.println("Поток B забрал значение ["+count+"]");
          for(int j=1;j<=count;j++){
             System.out.println("Поток В");
          }        
         target.notify();// Пробудить другой поток 
         target.wait();//Перейти в спящий режим самому
        }
      catch(InterruptedException e){}
    }
  } 
}
public class Beliaev_5variant_3_lab {

public static void main(String[] args) {  
  Callme target=new Callme();  
   for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){    
    new A(target);
    new B(target);
   }  
 }
}
```

P.s Возможно ли что это из-за того,что target.notify() и target.wait() блокирует и пробуждает сам себя и дальше дело не идёт?

Answer (score 1):

Опасно полагаться на последовательность notify-wait так просто. Необходимо ввести условную переменную, указывающую, что продюcер положил новую посылку в объект передачи (callme).

```
boolean canBeTaken;
```

Затем у потребителя:

```
while(!canBeTaken)
    cond.wait();
// Забираем посылку
canBeTaken = false; // Продюсер может класть снова
cond.notifyAll();
```

У продюсера:

```
while(canBeTaken)
    cond.wait();
// Выдаем посылку в callme
canBeTaken = true;
cond.notifyAll();
```

И доступ к canBeTaken должен быть также потокобезопасен, иначе дед-лок =)

Конечно, теперь продюсер блокируется до тех пор, пока потребитель не заберет значение. Чтобы этого избежать, можно организовать очередь. canBeTaken в этом случае будет указывать на то, что очередь не пуста.

Comment: Большое спасибо,заработало.А я ещё думал что boolean переменные это и есть флаги а оказывается флаги это что то другое =).